# What do these abbreviations mean in Rise of Nations?

Tags: terminology, rise-of-nations

I sometimes don't understand the slang in online games what do these mean?

1. ATM
2. DMC
3. BKAM
4. FSR
5. LISG
6. BCG
7. BCA
8. BCwN
9. FLT
10. FRT
11. SEM
12. CIA
13. Beemer Flight
14. Heavy Rain

Comment: ATM: Automated Teller Machine.  DMC: Devil May Cry.  BKAM: Burger King Autonomous Milkshakes.  FSR: From Soviet Russia.  LISG: Listen, I Sing Good.

Answer (score 5):

1. ATM- Antitank Missle (used against tanks)
2. DMC- Death Match Captial ( a game mode used for quicker games usually between 2 people)
3. BKAM- Bomb Ketch Attack Mode (attacking coastal areas light forts and cities)
4. FSR- Fire Ship Rush (used while playing with 6 or more people to eliminate large fleets for BKAM)
5. LISG- Light Infantry Stand Guard (used ONLY for cutting off trade routes for the wealth loot and crippling any expansion)
6. BCG- Bomb Catch Guard (Protect your Bomb catches, usually only in 2v2)
7. BCA- Bomb Catch Assault
8. BCWN- Burn/Control Win (If you can't hold a building, raze it)
9. FLT- Front Left Trip (Flanks ships or Beemer Flights on the left side)
10. FRT- Front Right Trip (Flanks ships or Beemer Flights on the right side)
11. SEM- Single Elimination Match (When a player from a team loses the whole team loses. Used for more team based games)
12. CIA - Use scouts and spies to use informers and bribe enemy units (usually only on peaceful).
13. Beemer Flight- An air attack style of fighter/bomber/fighter. This protects the bombers from attack.
14. Heavy Rain- Launch Missiles before attacking a city or base.

Comment: Can you explain some more about where these are used, not just give an dictionary term?  What they stand for doesn't help anything if you don't know how they're used.

Comment: A short, single sentence description still doesn't help very much.  You've got 30,000 characters to use; more explanation doesn't hurt, and indeed, will certainly help.